# Sql join two tables in a specific way

Tags: sql

Two tables have the same structure and only differ in values;

t1

```
id   param1 param2
---  ------ ------
id1  1      100
id1  2      101
```

t2

```
id   param1 param2
---  ------ ------
id1  1      501
id1  2      502
id1  3      503
```

What I need is the sql query which would result in the table like that:

```
id     param1 param2 param1 param2

id1    1      100
id1    2      101
id1                   1      501
id1                   2      502
id1                   3      503
```

Tried with different joins, but no luck. Is it possible?

Comment: What dbms is this? SQL Server?

Comment: Look closely at the data in your result . . . There's no join.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id1, param1, param2, null, null from t1
union all
select id1, null, null, param1, param2 from t2
```

And if you need t1 to always come before t2 records, then

```
select id1, param1, param2, param1_b, param2_b
from
(
select 1 as sorter, id1, param1, param2, null as param1_b, null as param2_b from t1
union all
select 2 as sorter, id1, null, null, param1, param2 from t2
) X
order by sorter
```

Comment: What a simple and sharp-witted solution, thank you very much.